# How to access array value and place into string

Tags: php, arrays

i have put a returned API object response into an array but now i want to access the array data, i get undefined index, this is my code.

```
 $paystack = new Yabacon\Paystack('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

 $trx = $paystack->transactions(["perPage"=>1, "amount"=>10000, "status"=>"success"]); //RETURNED OBJECT

 $array =  (array) $trx; //CONVERTED FROM OBJECT TO ARRAY.
```

When I `var_dump( (array) $trx );` i get

```
array(4) { ["status"]=> bool(true) ["message"]=> string(22) "Transactions retrieved" ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (22) { ["id"]=> int(901742) ["domain"]=> string(4) "test" ["status"]=> string(7) "success" ["reference"]=> string(13) "58c0e61ca5cce" ["amount"]=> int(10000) ["message"]=> NULL ["gateway_response"]=> string(10) "Successful" ["paid_at"]=> string(24) "2017-03-08T22:48:33.000Z" ["created_at"]=> string(24) "2017-03-08T22:48:11.000Z" ["channel"]=> string(4) "card" ["currency"]=> string(3) "NGN" ["ip_address"]=> string(14) "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" ["metadata"]=> object(stdClass)#23 (2) { ["custom_fields"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (3) { ["display_name"]=> string(13) "Mobile Number" ["variable_name"]=> string(13) "mobile_number" ["value"]=> string(14) "+xxxxxxxxxxxxx" } } ["referrer"]=> string(27) "http://localhost/b/checkout" } ["log"]=> object(stdClass)#24 (9) { ["time_spent"]=> int(24) ["attempts"]=> int(1) ["authentication"]=> NULL ["errors"]=> int(0) ["success"]=> bool(true) ["mobile"]=> bool(false) ["input"]=> array(0) { } ["channel"]=> NULL ["history"]=> array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#25 (3) { ["type"]=> string(5) "input" ["message"]=> string(55) "Filled these fields: card number, card expiry, card cvv" ["time"]=> int(20) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#26 (3) { ["type"]=> string(6) "action" ["message"]=> string(16) "Attempted to pay" ["time"]=> int(20) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#27 (3) { ["type"]=> string(7) "success" ["message"]=> string(17) "Successfully paid" ["time"]=> int(22) } [3]=> object(stdClass)#28 (3) { ["type"]=> string(5) "close" ["message"]=> string(11) "Page closed" ["time"]=> int(24) } } } ["fees"]=> int(150) ["fees_split"]=> NULL ["customer"]=> object(stdClass)#29 (8) { ["id"]=> int(102185) ["first_name"]=> string(0) "" ["last_name"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(23) "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" ["customer_code"]=> string(19) "CUS_xxxxxxxxxxx" ["phone"]=> string(0) "" ["metadata"]=> NULL ["risk_action"]=> string(7) "default" } ["authorization"]=> object(stdClass)#30 (12) { ["authorization_code"]=> string(15) "AUTH_xxxxxxxxx" ["bin"]=> string(6) "412345" ["last4"]=> string(4) "1381" ["exp_month"]=> string(2) "01" ["exp_year"]=> string(4) "2020" ["channel"]=> string(4) "card" ["card_type"]=> string(4) "visa" ["bank"]=> string(9) "TEST BANK" ["country_code"]=> string(2) "NG" ["brand"]=> string(4) "visa" ["reusable"]=> bool(true) ["signature"]=> string(24) "SIG_xxxxxxxxxxxx" } ["plan"]=> object(stdClass)#31 (0) { } ["subaccount"]=> object(stdClass)#32 (0) { } ["paidAt"]=> string(24) "2017-03-08T22:48:33.000Z" ["createdAt"]=> string(24) "2017-03-08T22:48:11.000Z" } } ["meta"]=> object(stdClass)#33 (6) { ["total"]=> int(6) ["total_volume"]=> int(60000) ["skipped"]=> int(0) ["perPage"]=> string(1) "1" ["page"]=> int(1) ["pageCount"]=> int(6) } }
```

What I want to do is, I want to get it in this format

```
$stats =   $array['data']['status'];  
$order_id =  $array['data']['id']; 
$transaction_method = $array['data']['channel']; 
$currency =  $array['data']['currency']; 
$reference =   $array['data']['reference']; 
$final_price =  $array['data']['amount']; 
$email_send =    $array['data']['customer']['email']; 
$day_paid =   $array['data']['paid_at']; 
$referring_page =  $array['data']['metadata']['referrer'];
```

But when i `ECHO` any variable out e.g i do `echo $stats` OR `echo $order_id` i get

```
 Notice: Undefined index: status in C:\xampp\htdocs\b\d\paystackorders.php on line 150

 Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\b\d\paystackorders.php on line 151.
```

How do i go around resolving this.

Comment: looks like data is an array ... ['data'][0] ? if that solves this issue, ponder as to why you are getting an array, and what you should do in case more are coming.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be `$array['data'][0]['status']`
and `$array['data'][0]['id']`
and so on...
This is because $array['data'] is an array of objects

The best way to go in my opinion is as follows:

```
$data = $array['data'][0];
```

And then access what you want :

```
$status = $data['status'];
$order_id = $data['id'];
```

Comment: this is what i get when i run that again "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\b\d\paystackorders.php:154 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\b\d\paystackorders.php on line 154" @mrateb

Comment: $array['data'] is an array of objects, its not an object. $array['data'][0] is an object however. 
Its better if show us what you're running now so we can help with this